# What are the events for "places search box" in Google Places API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Are there any events other than 'places_changed' event for the object returned from google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.createElement('nameForElement')) ?

You can see the places search box in this example. [Google Maps JavaScript API- places search box sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

Finally what I needed to be done is to clear the search box when I click it. But I think that there isn't a 'click' event for this search box. What is the right key word to catch a click event? 'mouseclick', 'click', 'onclick'... ?

Comment: are you doing it in js or android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click-listener to the `<input>` .

For the linked example it would be:

```
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(input,'click',function(){
    this.value='';
  });
```